# What parameter is missing from my function to extract a table from BigQuery to a GCS Bucket?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I have written a function to extract a table from BigQuery to a GCS Bucket, but I believe that my function is missing a parameter, and I am unsure what I need to add.

I have written the following function:

```
def extract_table(client):
    bucket_name = "extract_mytable_{}".format(_millis())
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = retry_storage_errors(storage_client.create_bucket)(bucket_name)

  
    project = "bigquery-public-data"
    dataset_id = "samples"
    table_id = "mytable"

    destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, "mytable.csv")
    dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

    extract_job = client.extract_table(
        table_ref,
        destination_uri,
        # Location must match that of the source table.
        location="US",
    )  # API request
    extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.
```

However, for my function: `def extract_table(client):`, there needs to be a second parameter alongside the `client` parameter, but I am not sure which one it is.

Does the dataset or table need to be added as the parameter?

Python Operator:

```
extract_bq_gcs = PythonOperator(
  task_id = "bq_extract_task",
  python_callable=extract_table
)
```

Comment: Is it a function in your code, or is it a Cloud Functions?

Comment: It is a function in my code. I am trying to write a function to extract a table from BQ to a GCS Bucket, which will then be called in a Python Operator - but I need some assistance.

Comment: Firstly, I don't understand your problem. You pas pass the argument that you want to your function (1 or many more!): The project, the dataset, the table, the output file, the output bucket,.... Customize it as you wish, you are the author, you have the power! Seconly if you use a "python operator", you use composer (or Airflow). In that case, you have a BigQuery operator that should do the job for you. Don't reinvent the wheel!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used the BigQueryOperator, but I am trying to accomplish the same task using a PythonOperator instead, as part of expanding my knowledge. Also, regarding the arguments for my function, should I pass the dataset and table?

Comment: It's a matter of customization. In general, it's not good to have hard coded values. Having them in parameter is better for the reusability

Comment: Ok, so I would have it like this? ```def extract_table():```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your function and no parameters are missing in the `extract_table` function :

```py
def extract_table():
    bucket_name = "bucket_name"
    client = bigquery.Client()

    project = "bigquery-public-data"
    dataset_id = "samples"
    table_id = "mytable"

    destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, "mytable.csv")
    dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, dataset_id)
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

    extract_job = client.extract_table(
        table_ref,
        destination_uri,
        # Location must match that of the source table.
        location="US",
    )  # API request
    extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.
```

The client object is retrieved with `bigquery.Client()`

You can also check the parameters into the `extract_table` function :

```py
def extract_table(
        self,
        source: Union[Table, TableReference, TableListItem, Model, ModelReference, str],
        destination_uris: Union[str, Sequence[str]],
        job_id: str = None,
        job_id_prefix: str = None,
        location: str = None,
        project: str = None,
        job_config: ExtractJobConfig = None,
        retry: retries.Retry = DEFAULT_RETRY,
        timeout: TimeoutType = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
        source_type: str = "Table",
    ) -> job.ExtractJob:
```

Only the parameters `source` and `destination_uris` are mandatories and you passed them.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response and clear solution to my problem. So, for the ```def extract_table():```, this would work when I add it to my DAG?

Comment: You can use the function `extract_table` in a `PythonOperator`, but as I said previously, it's better to use a built in `Airflow` operator for it like `BigQueryToGCSOperator`.

Comment: Like this? Please check main body of post.

Comment: Yes with `python_callable ` !!